# Badge on an item in GridView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a GridView in Flutter and I have to put a badge on it.
I have to achieve something like this.[image]

how can I add that badge on my code and make sure it works perfectly on different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do with the help of Stack inside the Gridview Builder same as below

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        // The content of the item goes here
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Item $index'),
          ),
        ),
        // The badge goes here
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Text(
              'Badge',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```